# Use Leaflet.MultiOptionsPolyline and leaflet.motion plugins together for the same polyline

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-plugins

I already search through the web but no clue on how to use `Leaflet.MultiOptionsPolyline` and `leaflet.motion` plugins together for same polyline.

There are two functions, one is:

```
L.motion.polyline([[50,0], [60,10]], {
    color: "transparent"
}, {
    auto: true,
    duration: 3000,
    easing: L.Motion.Ease.easeInOutQuart
}, {
    removeOnEnd: true,
    showMarker: true,
    icon: L.divIcon({html: "<i class='fa fa-car fa-2x' aria-hidden='true'></i>", iconSize: L.point(27.5, 24)})
}).addTo(map);
```

Another one is :

```
L.multiOptionsPolyline(points, {
    multiOptions: {
        optionIdxFn: function (latLng) {
            var i,
                altThresholds = [800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500];

            for (i = 0; i < altThresholds.length; ++i) {
                if (latLng.alt <= altThresholds[i]) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return altThresholds.length;
        },
        options: [
            {color: '#0000FF'}, {color: '#0040FF'}, {color: '#0080FF'},
            {color: '#00FFB0'}, {color: '#00E000'}, {color: '#80FF00'},
            {color: '#FFFF00'}, {color: '#FFC000'}, {color: '#FF0000'}
        ]
    },
    weight: 5,
    lineCap: 'butt',
    opacity: 0.75,
    smoothFactor: 1}).addTo(map);
```

But I really can't figure out how to call these two one after another.

https://github.com/hgoebl/Leaflet.MultiOptionsPolyline
https://github.com/Igor-Vladyka/leaflet.motion

*** update ***
My purpose is to create a polyline that can get the latitude and longitude of API records, and create a multicolor polyline that shows different intensity of the typhoon between each node of that polyline, and also shows the animation of the typhoon.

There is two function that I need to call (or maybe extend by another?)

Is there any way to call/initialize this two function, `L.multiOptionsPolyline` and `L.motion.polyline`?

Comment: hi i just edit the question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two plugins can be combined by using the same points source for both.

Since you didn't describe the format/structure of your data, the example below uses `[lat, lng, alt]` structure for point.

Code could then look something like this:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([46.2, 14.5], 8);

var points = [[46.0, 14.0, 700], [46.3, 14.2, 950], [46.2, 14.4, 1250], [46.3, 14.8, 1550], [46.5, 15, 1750]];
var altThresholds = [800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500];

L.multiOptionsPolyline(points, {
  multiOptions: {
    optionIdxFn: function (latLng) {
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < altThresholds.length; ++i) {
        if (latLng[2] <= altThresholds[i]) return i;
      }
      return altThresholds.length;
    },
    options: [
      {color: '#0000FF'}, {color: '#0040FF'}, {color: '#0080FF'},
      {color: '#00FFB0'}, {color: '#00E000'}, {color: '#80FF00'},
      {color: '#FFFF00'}, {color: '#FFC000'}, {color: '#FF0000'}
    ]
  },
  weight: 5,
  lineCap: 'butt',
  opacity: 0.75,
  smoothFactor: 1
}).addTo(map);      

L.motion.polyline(points, {
  color: "transparent"
}, {
  auto: true,
  duration: 3000,
  easing: L.Motion.Ease.easeInOutQuart
}, {
  removeOnEnd: true,
  showMarker: true,
  icon: L.divIcon({html: "<i class='fa fa-car fa-2x' aria-hidden='true'></i>", iconSize: L.point(27.5, 24)})
}).addTo(map);
```

This gives the following result:

[image]